# ESRI Basemap No High Resolution

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, arcgis-online-basemaps

Did ESRI drop their high res. basemaps. I made a map in November and today I needed to make a small adjustment to it. The high resolution basemap is gone and my map looks bad. I have attached the 2 maps to show the vast difference. Has ESRI done something or is there a setting that I am missing? 
I am using ArcGIS 10.4.1 for desktop.

[image: HighResMap]

[image: LowResMap]

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a lat/long so that we can view the available imagery for your AOI?

Comment: It's in western North Dakota.

Comment: What is a lat/long in western North Dakota that will enable us to go to that location?

Comment: 47°39'4.48"N  103°13'48.76"W